# Is there a way to install extension in MSVS2010 with /RootSuffix (experimental) switch?

Tags: visual-studio

MSVS2010 has a way of having experimental configurations using an [*Experimental Instance*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166560.aspx).

But if I try and install an extension using the *Extension Manager* within an *Experimental Instance*, it crashes.  Is there a way around this?

It's not very useful experimental setup if all that it can do is the base install settings. :(

Comment: What do you mean by multiple configurations?